# Hibernate - Set filtered on column in parent and child tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jsf, hibernate-mapping

I have a `Node` which is associated with `NodeData`s. These `NodeData`s have revisions, and Node has a column `latestRevision` which tells it which is the last revision.

I'm trying to figure out the mapping I need to get the set below filtered by the `latestRevision` in `Node`.

```
 <class name="Node" table="RatNodes">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set fetch="join" name="nodeDatas" table="RatNodeData" inverse="true" access="field" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="dataOrder asc">
        <key column="nodeID" on-delete="cascade"/>
        <one-to-many class="NodeData"/>
        <filter name="revisionFilter" condition="revision = latestRevision"/>
    </set>
    <property name="questionNumber" access="field"/>
    <property name="type" access="field"/>
</class>
<class name="NodeData" table="RatNodeData">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="nodeID" access="field"/>
        <key-property name="key" access="field" column="dataKey"/>
        <key-property name="order" access="field" column="dataOrder"/>
        <key-property name="revision" access="field"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="value" access="field" type="EncodedStringUserType" column="dataValue"/>
</class>
```

The result of this mapping when I enable the filter is an error:

```
Caused by: com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLException: Invalid column name 'latestRevision'.
```

The query it spits out is:

```
select nodedatas0_.nodeID as nodeID1_, nodedatas0_.dataKey as dataKey1_, nodedatas0_.dataOrder as dataOrder1_, nodedatas0_.revision as revision1_, nodedatas0_.nodeID as nodeID46_0_, nodedatas0_.dataKey as dataKey46_0_, nodedatas0_.dataOrder as dataOrder46_0_, nodedatas0_.revision as revision46_0_, nodedatas0_.dataValue as dataValue46_0_ from RatNodeData nodedatas0_ where  nodedatas0_.revision = nodedatas0_.latestRevision and nodedatas0_.nodeID=? order by nodedatas0_.dataOrder asc
```

I can tell this is wrong as it's looking for `latestRevision` on `NodeData` but I'm not sure how to tell it to look on `Node` instead. Is this possible in hibernate? Seems like a pretty simple query if I were just using SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing this instead of trying to do it in the mapping file:

```
List datas = session.createCriteria(NodeData.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("nodeID", this.id))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("revision", this.latestRevision))
                .list();
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this or not. Would love to hear about a mapping file solution too.

Comment: Hello Philippe, Are you still on this solution? IMHO looks good, but I would like to hear about a mapping one too! You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283199/use-a-filter-within-a-composite-id-in-hibernate

Comment: I haven't worked on that project in a while but as far as I know it's still working that way.

Comment: Thanks Philippe! I will let you know if I manage to get to it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any filter or  'latestRevision' as filter-param. So it will not come to know that what actually the entity means.
Try using following.

For further help have a look at the [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html).